# AWS Lambda SES and AWS Pinpoint Promise.all not working

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, promise, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

would appreciate the help. I have 2 promises, but i do not want one promise to run if the other promise rejects. for some reason, even when the voice call promise is erroring, or the email promise is erroring, the other promise is still running.

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const ses = new aws.SES({region: 'us-west-2'});
const pinpointsmsvoice = new aws.PinpointSMSVoice({region: 'us-west-2'});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const parsed = JSON.parse(event.data)
    const foodArray = parsed.food
    const callParams = {
        Content: {
            SSMLMessage: {
                LanguageCode : "en-US",
                Text : "<speak>Hello Restaurant. You have a new online order from. " + parsed.user.firstName + ". Please check your email and enter the order into the P O S system. Thank you. Goodbye.</speak>",
                VoiceId: "Salli"
            }
        },
        OriginationPhoneNumber: "[+1111111111]",
        DestinationPhoneNumber: "<+incorrect number inputted here>"
    };

const email = ()=> {
        let buffer = ''
        for (let i = 0; i<foodArray.length; i++) { 
                buffer += `<p> ${i+1}. ${foodArray[i].name} <br></br>    quantity: ${foodArray[i].quantity} <br></br>    special instructions: ${foodArray[i].instructions || "none"} <br></br>    if sold out: ${foodArray[i].soldOut}`
            }
        let customer = `<br><br> <br></br> Customer: ${parsed.user.firstName} ${parsed.user.lastName},<br/> phone number: ${parsed.user.phoneNumber},<br/> email: ${parsed.user.email}`

        const params = {
            Destination: {
             ToAddresses: ["someone@gmail.com"]
           },
          Message: {
               Body: {
                    Html: {

                         Charset: "UTF-8",
                         Data: "<html><body><h1>Hello CP</h1> <h4>You have a new online order.</h4>" + buffer + customer + "</body></html>"
                     },
                  Text: {
                            Charset: "UTF-8",
                           Data: ""
                      }
                  },
                Subject: { Data: `New Online Order from ${parsed.user.firstName} ${parsed.user.lastName}`

              }
             },
         Source: "<incorrect email inputted here>"
        };
return params
}

const sendPromise = ses.sendEmail(email()).promise();
const callPromise = pinpointsmsvoice.sendVoiceMessage(callParams).promise()



Promise.all([sendPromise, callPromise]).then(function(values) {
  callback(null, values);
}).catch(function(values) {callback(null,values)});
```

thanks for the help im new at this

Comment: Promise.all doesn't control if promises run or not, it just waits for all of them to resolve, or the first to reject ... one rejecting does not stop the other promises from completing

Comment: You only have two promises, I don't think it will cause lot of performance overhead if you execute them consecutively. Why don't you run the voice call promise first since it seems to be the one to fail compared to SES. You can run SES next. Do you think it's acceptable.